# How can I bind a LINQ table to a gridview?

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

I'm trying to make a booking system where all customer names can be displayed associated with a particular booking, once the booking ID is entered, I have a linq table that i don't know how to connect with an SQL database and display on a gridview, this is my code below

```
public partial class BookingGuests : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private HotelConferenceEntities datacontext = new HotelConferenceEntities();



    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {


                int id = int.Parse(BookID.Text.ToString());
                tblBooking booking = datacontext.tblBookings.SingleOrDefault(x => x.BookingID == id);

                tblVenue venue = datacontext.tblVenues.SingleOrDefault(x => x.VenueID == booking.Venue);


                List<tblCustomer> customers = new List<tblCustomer>();
                List<tblBookingGuest> guests = booking.tblBookingGuests.ToList();



                    foreach (tblBookingGuest guest in guests)
                    {
                        tblCustomer newcust = datacontext.tblCustomers.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.CustomerID == guest.CustomerID);
                        customers.Add( newcust);


                    }

                    int count = customers.Count;
                    GridView1.DataSource = customers;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What is a Linq table?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or LinqToSQL framework here?

Comment: In either way - any entity model file (**.edmx** for Entity Framework and **.dbml** for LinqToSql) could be opened in design mode where you could click on the background and, then, in the *Properties Window* set the standard connection string to your SQL database.

Comment: Do you receive an error ? What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not my habit to say this to anyone, but seen your previous almost identical questions, could you please first study C#, LINQ, etc. yourself in stead of spamming StackOverflow with these low quality questions? And if questions don't get answers you like, _edit_ the question ins stead of reposting it.

Comment: comment unrelated to your question - you really should move your data binding out of the postback event into it's own method and call that method when appropriate. It will save you many headaches.

Comment: It's not a LINQ table... it's a collection of objects.  Looks like your code is doing what you need. What isn't working?